# Angular place holder text is getting hide under the line

Tags: angular

I am using below code to display placeholder

```
<mat-form-field>
                <mat-label style="margin-top:auto;">Search By Name</mat-label>
                <input matInput [(ngModel)]="searchAllPBS" id="search">             
</mat-form-field>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyZVy.png)
Please find the image attached. I am not sure why text is getting hide under line.
Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use placeholder attribute of input tag

```
<mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [(ngModel)]="searchAllPBIS" id="search" placeholder="Search By Name" />             
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Thanks Gourav, Thanks for quick reply. I have tried given solution but its not working. I am thinking if i can apply any style in <input tag so that text will not get hide under the underline.

Comment: Have you added material theme in your styles.scss?